# Crear un json en postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, post

¿Cómo puedo crear un json con todos los datos de una tabla?

Actualmente tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT to_json(c.*) FROM auxiliary.conceptos_rubros c
```

Pero se esta creando un **json** para cada fila así:

[image: AQUI EL EJEMPLO]

Mi duda es como puedo agregar todos esos *json* en una sola fila y **en un solo json** con todos los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `json_agg`, para retornar un arreglo `json` con todos esos `json`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT json_agg(to_json(c.*)) FROM auxiliary.conceptos_rubros c
```